# How to get the desired value from this request?

Tags: python, watson

I am using a rest api model to make the following request:

```
def predict(path):
    with open(path) as img:
            res = vr.classify(images_file=img, threshold=0, classifier_ids=['food'])
            print res
```

When I run my script I get:

```
{u'images': [{u'image': u'/tacos.jpg', u'classifiers': [{u'classes': [{u'score': 0.0495783, u'class': u'pizza'}, {u'score': 0.553117, u'class': u'tacos'}], u'classifier_id': u'food', u'name': u'food-test'}]}], u'custom_classes': 2, u'images_processed': 1}
```

However I would like to get just the class with higher value as follows:

```
this is the corresponding class: tacos
```

So I would like to appreciate support to modify my function in order to obtain the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the python-native [`sorted`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sorted) function, getting the higher value per classifier's id ? Using (too) big object names *so as to be clear*, and avoiding *code golfing*, you may want to do as follows

```
def predict(path):
    with open(path) as img:
        res = vr.classify(images_file=img, threshold=0, classifier_ids=['food'])

        dict_of_higher_value_per_ = {} # in order to record and reuse values sooner or later.
        for image in res['images']:
            for classifier in image['classifiers']:
                classes       = classifier['classes']
                classifier_id = classifier['classifier_id']
                sorted_scores = sorted(classes, 
                                       key=lambda class_:class_['score'],
                                       reverse=True)
                best_match    = sorted_scores[0] # which corresponds to the best score since elements are sorted.
                dict_of_higher_value_per_[classifier_id] = best_match

                print "Classifier '{cid}' says this is the corresponding class: {class}".format(cid=classifier_id,
                                                                                                **best_match)
```

which prints

```
Classifier 'food' says this is the corresponding class: tacos
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the support I really appreciate this

Answer (score 1):

This is a dictionary, so you can just iterate through the 'classes' and find the highest score.

Disclaimer: I'm not a python2 or watson user.

To access the classes

```
res['images'][0]['classifiers'][0]['classes']
```

So to iterate through the classes...

```
highest_class = ['', 0]
for class in res['images'][0]['classifiers'][0]['classes']:
    if class['score'] > highest_class[1]:
        highest_class = [class['class'], [class['score']
print "this is the corresponding class: " + highest_class[0]
```

Now of course, if you have more than 1 classifiers, you'll have to have another outside for loop to iterate through the classifiers (if you need that functionality)

Comment: If you downvoted my answer, Could I have an explanation why?